# Loading custom Python Layer in Caffe-Import Error

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I've written my own Caffe layer in Python (maskextractor.py). When training the network from scratch, it worked well. But once I've tried finetuning from the saved network:

```
../caffe/build/tools/caffe train -solver solverFCN8s_MCN_newmodule.prototxt -snapshot snapshot/train8MCNs_borders_pascal_maskextractor_iter_1.solverstate
```

the error I got is failed import of the new layer:

```
I1127 09:38:40.254966  3102 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer maskextractor
ImportError: No module named mask_extractor
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'
*** Aborted at 1511775520 (unix time) try "date -d @1511775520" if you are using GNU date ***
```

Clearly Caffe can't find the new layer. I've added it to the Pythonpath via `sys.path.insert` and then copied to `caffe/python/caffe/` an recompiled pycaffe, but it didn't help either.

EDIT: this only happens when I finetune. If I start from solver:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
caffe_dir = "/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/caffe/python"
sys.path.insert(0,caffe_dir)
import caffe
newmodule_dir = "../lib/mask_extractor"
sys.path.insert(0, newmodule_dir)
import mask_extractor
#
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(0)

# continue from the saved weights
weights = 'snapshot/train8MCNs_borders_pascal_adadelta_maskextractor_new_iter_1.caffemodel'
solver=caffe.get_solver('solverFCN8s_MCN_adadelta_maskextractor_new.prototxt')
solver.net.copy_from(weights)

solver.solve()
```

everything works fine. But I want to continue training from he snapshot. In such case I get the error above. PythonPath looks like

```
print sys.path

 ['/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/caffe/python', '../lib/mask_extractor', '/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/caffe/python', '/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/voc-fcn8s', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.9.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fast_rcnn-0.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

EDIT 2: this is how the sys.path and the import looks like

```
from subprocess import call
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
#caffe_dir = "/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/caffe-crfrnn/python"
#caffe_dir = "/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/caffe/python"
#sys.path.insert(0,caffe_dir)
#import caffe
newmodule_dir = "/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/lib/mask_extractor"
sys.path.insert(0, newmodule_dir)
import mask_extractor
#import caffe
#
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(0)
print sys.path
# continue from the saved weights

call('/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/voc-fcn8s/run_ft.sh', shell=True)'
```

and sys.path is now

```
'/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/caffe/python', '/home/ICTDOMAIN/453615/Downloads/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/lib/mask_extractor'
```

Yet the exact same problem persists. As I mentioned before, this only comes up when I invoke caffe from the `tools` dir. When I create caffe net with the solver rather than solverstate, no problems are reported.

Comment: You should copy it to caffe/python, not to caffe/python/caffe, BTW. Unless you wish to import it through 'import caffe.maskextractor'

Comment: Didn't work. I compiled pycaffe again and added PYTHONPATH ='/path/to/init' but still same error. Do I need to compile anything else?

Comment: seems like `PYTHONPATH` issue. use the same as the one used for the initial training.

Comment: @Shai: I copied mask_extractor.py to caffe/python/caffe and added 'from .mask_extractor import MaskExtractor' and still the same error! What did I do wrong? This only happens when I run caffe from bash, not python script

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for printing your `PYTHONPATH`. I'm pretty sure that changing your mask_extractor path to be an absolute path will fix your `ImportError`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Jonathan: no , sorry it didn't :( same error

Comment: @Alex, can you update your question to give your new PYTHONPATH and the follow the instruction in my step 2. Tell me the results when you go to the directory of your caffe executable and try importing your module from Python.

Comment: @Jonathan: I did exactly as you told me, I still get the same error: ImportError: No module named mask_extractor_zero, apparently pycaffe for some reason can't find path to this dir and this only happens when I invoke caffe from tools dir, not create a solver and add weights

Comment: @Alex, How did you build and compile caffe? Did you have WITH_PYTHON_LAYER enabled (if you used Makefile.config?). Could you do `make clean`, rebuild caffe, save logs, and post links to this log files with the corresponding commands you used? You might also want to check to make sure you are using the version of Python that Caffe is built with.

Comment: @Jonathan: OK I resolved the problem by using solver.restore('solverstate_file'). For some reason the caffe train way didn't like me. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1: Make sure you can import your layer from Python

To test your python code, you should be able to open `python` and type `from module_name import layer_name` where `module_name` and `layer_name` is what you use in the prototxt definition.

As indicated, you passed this step.

### Step 2: Make sure your PYTHONPATH is valid

If your PYTHONPATH is valid, you should be able to go to the directory of your caffe excutable and then import your module. What is the result when you perform this step?

The paths in `PYTHONPATH` should all be absolute.

Comment: well I did that, but whenver I use tools/caffe train instead of the solver, I keep getting this error

Comment: So you don't get any errors when you do the above? Can you give us the  output of `echo $PYTHONPATH` verbatim? Are you sure it is valid? Can you also give us the part of your prototxt where you use this layer?

Comment: No errors are reported when I import the module, but when I run script, I get that one